# Why can you not just simply delete a folder with php?

Tags: php

Not sure if this is the correct place to post this but I would like to know why you cannot just simply delete a folder. Why do you have to loop through every file and delete them before deleting the folder? Are there any new functions that allow you to just delete a folder without recursion?

Comment: Because you can't, you have to make sure the directory is empty first, as in most operating systems when using the command line.

Comment: @adeneo It seems like a pretty common practice to want to delete folders with files in them. Why hasn't PHP added a function to do this yet?

Comment: I don't know, probably because it seems rather straight forward to let you do it yourself.

Comment: I think for security reasons, you could do it by mistake and take all your folder away...

Comment: `exec('rm -rf your_dir/');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can, but it is operating system dependant. Provided the user running PHP has execute permissions on the executables and delete permissions on the directories and files to be deleted.

```
if ($path = realpath(__DIR__ . '/subdirectory')) {
    if (\DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR === '/') {
        /* Linux or Mac */
        `rm -rf $path`;
        /* shell_exec('rm -rf ' . $path); //alternative */
    } elseif (\DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR === '\\') {
        /* Windows */
        `rd /s /q "$path"`;
        /* shell_exec('rd /s /q "' . $path . '"'); //alternative */
    }
}
```

See more information on:

- `shell_exec` http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php
- `exec` http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php